# What happens when a python function that takes arguments called without defining parameters?

Tags: python, function, sorting

```
L=[5,10,4,2,8,7]
def compare(a,b):
    return cmp(b,a)

L.sort(compare)
print (L[-2])
L.sort()
print (L[2])
```

When this code is run, why a exception is not thrown since the function compare called within sort function has not been given exactly two arguments?
when the code is run it gives the output as,

```
4
5
```

Comment: Why do you assume that `compare()` isn't called with two arguments? You pass `compare()` as the `cmp` argument to `list.sort()` and the callback gets called with two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling directly the function

You are passing to the sort function a 'pointer' or a 'reference' to the function that will be used as a comparator

if you need more debugging info add a line that print what is being compared as follow

```
L=[5,10,4,2,8,7]
def compare(a,b):
    print 'comparing ',a,b
    return cmp(b,a)

L.sort(compare)
```

and you will also notice that the number of calls depends on L dis-order

there are several ways to solve the problem of order an array
some of that are merge-sort , binary-sort and still others

this is the [link](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c?revision=69227&view=markup) to the source code of python list object

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling compare in L.sort(compare). You are just passing a reference to the function that will be called internally by sort.

You don't need any other arguments for that. Remember that in order to call a function you use (), so if you were actually calling it you would have written L.sort(compare())

Comment: So how does the sort function define the a,b parameters?

Comment: It doesn't. It just expects a function that it can call. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort